# AdyenApi implementation

Tags: php, omnipay

We want to use ominipay using AdyenApi as driver. Do you have plans to add this gateway to be supported soon? We're thinking of developing a new driver since we can't fine any valid driver for that and maybe it's a good oportunity to contribute.

Many thanks.

Regards.

Victor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a driver already built, here: https://packagist.org/packages/peopleperhour/omnipay-adyen

If that doesn't work for you then either contact the package owner or get back with any questions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but that driver is for HPP not for Adyen API.

Comment: Ah, noted. Then you could either contribute your own driver or pay someone else to do it. There are a few people around who will develop drivers for hire, including myself